# How many different groups of 12 people can be chosen from a group of 30. More restrictions on details.

Tags: probability

How many different groups of 12 people can be chosen from a group of 30. Note: the group of 30 contains:

1. 2 people that will not work together (pick neither, or pick one, but not both) and
2. 2 people that will not be separated (pick neither or both).

So far I got these:

28C12 (Pick neither) +
28C11 (Pick 1st only) +
28C11 (Pick 2nd only) +

Now I'm working on the "2 people that will not be separated (pick neither or both).

Im not sure if my approach on the 1st restriction was correct. My guess for the 2nd restriction is:

26C12 (Pick neither)
26C10 (Pick both)

Comment: Count all possible combinations that simultaneously meet **both** conditions. So in principle $(3)(2)$ cases, but effectively only $4$. Each case will involve a ${}_{26}C_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call $(A,B)$ group $E$ (enemies), and $(C,D)$ group $F$ (friends)

Valid selections from the restrictive groups $E-F$ are:

$(0-0) + (1-0) + (0-2) + (1-2)$, thus

$\binom{26}{12} + \binom{26}{11}\binom21 + \binom{26}{10}\binom22 + \binom{26}{9}\binom21\binom22$

Comment: What does the last addend mean?

Comment: $1$ from the "enemy" group, $2$ from the "friends" group, and , of course,  $9$ from the general  group to make up $12$

Comment: I'm a noob in shortcuts. What does $1$ mean?

Comment: $1$ person , what else !

Comment: oh ok in my phone there's a dollar sign in between the numbers

Comment: Oh, Mathjax malfunction ! :)